# Transferring a local R package to bitbucket

Tags: r, package, repository, bitbucket, shinyapps

I have created an R package, which I use in a shiny app that works locally. However, I found that I cannot deploy this package onto shinyapps.io because devtools() cannot automatically infer where my package's home is if I install it locally.

One solution is to put the package on Github and install from there, but my package needs to be private. Thus I want to put the package onto bitbucket, which has free private repos.

The problem is, I am having trouble understanding how to put my local package into a  bitbucket repo. Can someone point me to the solution?